# Junit has partially covering the code for webclient's doOnError method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, webclient

an abstract class contains a generic method to make rest call using webclient
Webclinet build is auto-wired through constructor
abstract class structure and and its corresponding test classes have given below

```
    @Component
    public abstract class client{
    
       @Autowired WebClient.Builder builder;
    
      public <T,R> Mono<R> callApi(T req,Class<R> resp,String mode) {
        return WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build()
            .post()
            .uri("/v1/student")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .bodyValue(req)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(resp)
            .doOnError(err->handleError(err,mode));
      }
    
      private void handleError(Throwable err,String mode) {
        if(mode){
          throw new CustomExp1();
        }
        throw new CustomExp2();
      }
    }
```

```
On Error scenario Global Controller advise will catch the exception and return the response Entity based upon the CustomExp throw.
```

Junit- code for testing the apiCall of abstract class is given below,
creating a sample class and extending the abstract class and creating an spy mock of the sample class to call the abstract class method.

```
  public class MainClient{
  
  public static class MainClient extends client(){
  public MainClient(WebClient.builder webClientBuilder)
  super(webClientBuilder)
    }

      @InjectMock
      @spy
      MainClient spyMainClient

      @Mock
      private WebClient.builder webClientBuilder=WebClient.builder();
  
      @Mock
      private WebClient buildMock;
  
      @Mock
      private WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec uriMock;   
  
  
      @Mock
      private WebClient.RequestBodySpec bodySpecMock;
  
      
      @Mock
      private WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec headersSpecMock;
      
      
      @Mock
      private WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpecMock;
  
     @Mock
      private Mono<Post> responseMock;
  
  @Test
  callTestError(){
  Mono<Post> response= Mono.error(new Throwable("Error"));
  
  when(webClientBuilder).thenReturn(buildMock);
  when(buildMock.post()).thenReturn(uriMock);      
  when(uriMock.uri(anyString())).thenReturn(bodySpecMock);
  when(bodySpecMock.contentType(MediaType.JSON)).thenReturn(bodySpecMock);
  doReturn(headersSpecMock).when(bodySpecMock).bodyValue(any());
  doReturn(responseSpecMock).when(headersSpecMock).retrieve();
  when(responseSpecMock.bodyToMono(Post.class).thenReturn(responseMock));
  when(responseMock.doOnError(any())).thenReturn(response)
  
  spyMainClient.callApi(new Req(),Post.class,true);
  
  }
  }
```

```
when executing the test case, it's completing successfully, but when i look at jacoco report  .doOnError(err->handleError(err,mode)); section of webclient is partially completed.
```

can someone help me to resolve the issue

Comment: Above code is working and coverage is 100% if i change the doOnerror method to doOnError(err->{
 if(mode){
          throw new CustomExp1();
        }
        throw new CustomExp2();
});

Comment: Still not sure why code coverage is partial if i add separate method inside doOnError

Answer (score 0):

I think doOnError is an exception path and will be only be executed if something fails. So you should another test for failure scenario in which you should fail it at somepoint like:

```java
 when(bodySpecMock.contentType(MediaType.JSON)).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());
```

Error stream should pick this failure and execute doOnError block

Comment: No the Reactive chain will not catch this exception on doOnError, you have to wrap exception in Mono.error and then your doOnError will be triggered.

Example- doReturn(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("test"))).when(bodySpecMock).contentType(MediaType.JSON);

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap exception in Mono.error and then your doOnError will be triggered. Example-

```
doReturn(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("test"))).when(bodySpecMock).contentType(MediaType.JSON);
```